# Angular DI: Injecting a Service with multiple parameter values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, frontend

#### Introduction

I am coding some services for an Angular project, were I am trying to follow good practices (such as *SOLID principles*) to avoid coupling and depend on abstractions.

For one of these services, I have defined the following interface:

```js
interface BrowserMessageChannel<T> {
  postMessage(message: T): void;
  onMessage$(): Observable<T>;
  close(): void;
}
```

This *Browser Message Channel* is nothing more that the abstraction, which hides the implementation details, of having a shared message space that apps opened in different tabs can use to communicate between each other. This API will also use observables so clients can subscribe to new messages.

#### Implementation

This service could be implemented in many ways but I decided to make use of the [BroadcastChannel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) underneath:

```js
class BcBrowserMessageChannel<T> implements BrowserMessageChannel<T> {
  private onMessage: Subject<T>;

  constructor(private broadcastChannel: BroadcastChannel) {
    this.setUpOnMessage();
  }

  postMessage(message: T): void {
    this.broadcastChannel.postMessage(message);
  }

  onMessage$(): Observable<T> {
    return this.onMessage;
  }

  close(): void {
    this.broadcastChannel.close();
    this.onMessage.complete();
  }

  private setUpOnMessage(): void {
    this.onMessage = new Subject();

    this.broadcastChannel.onmessage = ({ data }: { data: T }) => {
      this.onMessage.next(data);
    };
  }
}
```

And provide it so whenever a `BrowserMessageChannel` is needed we will have a particular implementation under the hoods:

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: BrowserMessageChannel,
    useClass: BcBrowserMessageChannel
  }]
})
class CommunicationModule {
}
```

### Problem within the Angular Framework

A `BroadcastChannel` object must be passed into the `BcBrowserMessageChannel`'s constructor and a channel name (string) must be passed also into the `BroadcastChannel`'s constructor too. In plain TypeScript code, this would look like the following:

```js
const bc: BroadCastChannel = new BroadcastChannel(channelName);
const channel: BrowserMessageChannel = new BcBrowserMessageChannel(bc);
```

How can I fit this situation in an Angular solution?

How to achieve this with the framework's Dependency Injection mechanism, where the following would not be enough?:

```js
@Component({
  ...
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(private browserMessageChannel: BrowserMessageChannel) {
    // In my scenario, I would need to specify a channel name to 
    // BrowserMessageChannel, so in this component I can post messages and
    // subscribe to new ones in that particular one
  }
}
```